# C# Windows Phone 8.1 Language selection

Tags: c#, selection, windows-phone-8.1, multilingual

I hope this wasn't asked before, I couldn't find an easy solution in MSDN or here.

The windows phone 8.1 application is deployed in more than one language.
To do so I use the default language (english) in `Strings\en-US\Ressources.resw` and installed the [Multilingual App Toolkit](http://dev.windows.com/de-de/develop/multilingual-app-toolkit) with all further languages added there.

To change the language, I have the following code:

```
private void changeLang(string cul)
{
    Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = cul;

    Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();

    if (Frame != null)
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
}
```

which can be called by

```
changeLang("en-US");
```

After that I have to restart the application (couldn't make it work without restart yet).

The problem is my implementation. I created a page called `Settings` where I want to provide the user the possibility to change the language.

Now I want to provide the user a `ComboBox` with all the languages I have translated. By default the selected `ComboBoxItem` should show the current language of the application (not the Systems language, as the user might already have had changed the language).

Here my solution to the problem, I hope this might be useful to others as well.

First we create a new `struct`:

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

Then on the `OnNavigate` part on the Form we add the following code:

```
settings_language_cb.Items.Add(new ComboboxItem { Text = "Deutsch", Value = "de-DE" });
settings_language_cb.Items.Add(new ComboboxItem { Text = "English", Value = "en-US" });

var curLangItem = settings_language_cb.Items.SingleOrDefault(x => (x as ComboboxItem).Value.ToString() == CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);

settings_language_cb.SelectedItem = curLangItem;
settings_language_cb.PlaceholderText = (curLangItem as ComboboxItem).Text;
```

And that's all.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/artem-zinnatullin/8062647 this may help you to change the language without restarting the app. It worked for me in my windows phone 8 app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
class LanguageCode
{
    string Name { get; set; },
    string CodeName { get; set; }
}

var langs = new List<LanguageCode>();
langs.Add(new LanguageCode() { Name = "English", CodeName = "en-US" });
langs.Add(new LanguageCode() { Name = "Deutsch", CodeName = "de-DE" });
//    ... and so on ...

settings_language_cb.Items.Add(langs);
settings_language_cb.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

On the ComboBox, change the code to:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var si = settings_language_cb.SelectedItem as LanguageCode;
    if(si != null) 
        changeLang(si.CodeName);  // changeLang("de-DE");
}
```

Comment: Haha thank you very much, just did like EXACTLY the same (thus I managed to solve the selected Item problem). Thank you very much anyway!! (I'll post my code in the question and will mark you as the solution)

Answer (score 1):

@MrEko

it's easy to get the selected item.

First you have to create a `SelectionChanged` event in your `XAML` Combobox and then you will get the selected item as following:

```
(myXAMLComboBox.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value.ToString();
```

and here the whole thing in action. (note that `oldLang` is a constant that I save when I change the language and `changeLang` is the function that changes the language). And of cause, after changing the language, you have to restart your App, so it takes effect.

```
private void Page_Settings_LanguageComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (oldLang != (PageSettings_Language_cb.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value.ToString())
  {
    try
    {
        changeLang((PageSettings_Language_cb.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value.ToString());
        ShowRestartMessageBox();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
  }
}
```