# windows phone 8.1 language selection

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Change the language on windows phone 8.1 From The app not need to change language and then restart the phone , If i clicked on combobox and choose Arabic or English change the application UI Language [image: Help Plz!!!]

I Tested this but didn't work !! [C# Windows Phone 8.1 Language selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26074531/c-sharp-windows-phone-8-1-language-selection)

Comment: can you provide more details? it is not clear what you want to achieve. Where is the language changing code?

Comment: Do you want to change the language in your application or on your windows phone? Could you provide code behind? Thanks

Comment: Just in the application

Comment: Follow the steps on this post which explains for `WP8` could give an idea! http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/02/01/tips-for-localizing-windows-phone-8-xaml-apps-part1/